# Check key existence in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I am working with API calls and thus Python dictionaries.

However, for the same request, I don't always key the same keys, and I'd like to know when I can call a key without an Exception...

Let's say I have

```
test = {'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':'e'}}}}
```

Sometimes key d will exist, sometimes it won't. Sometimes c won't even exist.

I'd like to, somehow, check if `test['a']['b']['c']['d']` exists, in one line.

What I've tried so far:

- Using `test.get('a', {}).get('b', {}).get('c', {}).get('d', {})`. Works fine but it's a mess, sometimes I have 5-6 nested dictionaries with really long names...
- Using try/except block which is nice, but usually if `test['a']['b']['c']['d']` does not exist, I will try calling `test['a']['b']['e']['f']` to check if that one exists, thus I would need to add a try/catch for every of my if statements, as if I am not wrong, if an exception is catch, try block is not executed anymore.

I was maybe trying to look to a somekind of reflexive way to do it, calling a function with the name of my "object" as a string, that would check if every key exists, and if it does, return the object itself.

Any thoughts?

The usage behind it would be, omitting useless case, and assuming sometimes the info is in test['a']['b']['c']['d'], sometimes in test['a']['b']['f'] :

```
if test['a']['b']['c']['d'] **exists**:
    do sthg with the value of test['a']['b']['c']['d']
elif test['a']['b']['f'] **exists**:
    do sthg else with the value of test['a']['b']['f']
else:
    do sthg different
```

If I put a try/except there, won't the first exception stop the execution and don't let me execute the elif?

Moreover, I really like the way of calling `test['a']['b']['c']['d']` better than giving a list of keys. In fact, I want it to be as transparent as possible for me and for the people who will read/use my code.

Comment: What do you need your code to do? It seems that the try/except block is the correct approach. Do you want e.g. the depth at which it fails?

Comment: @remram If the key d doest not exist, my information will likely be in another key.
`if test['a']['b']['c']['d'] **exists**:
     do sthg
elif test['a']['b']['e'] **exists**:
     do sthg else
else:
     do sthg else`
If I'm not wrong, if test['a']['b']['c']['d'] does not exist and everything is within a try/catch, the elif won't even be executed, right ?

Comment: This is similar to [Access python nested dictionary items via a list of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14692690/12892)

Comment: @cristian-ciupitu Not really. In the other, the OP wants to access the values via a list of keys, assuming the key exist.
To be honest, I even like the normal way of calling test['a']['b']['c'] better than giving a list of keys, which all solutions are using for now :/

Comment: Actually I like your original approach of the `.get(key,{})` pretty well -and better than the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with JSON, you can write a simple class to use with the dict as it is imported.

Given the following bit of JSON:

```
>>> js='{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": "e"}}}}'
```

It would usually be decoded into a Python dict if it is comprised of object pairs:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(js)
{u'a': {u'b': {u'c': {u'd': u'e'}}}}
```

As a normal Python dict, it is subject to `KeyError` with missing keys. You can use the [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) hook to override `KeyErrors` and achieve your original structure:

```
class Mdict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return False
```

Now test that:

```
>>> md=Mdict({'a':Mdict({'b':Mdict({'c':Mdict({'d':'e'})})})})
>>> if md['a']['b']['d']:
...    print md['a']['b']['d']
... elif md['a']['b']['c']:
...    print 'elif', md['a']['b']['c']  
... 
elif {'d': 'e'}
```

Each level of the dict needs to be an `Mdict` vs a normal Python `dict`. If you are working with JSON, however, this is really easy to achieve. Just apply [object_pairs_hook](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) as you decode the JSON:

```
>>> js
'{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": "e"}}}}'
>>> md=json.loads(js, object_pairs_hook=Mdict)
```

And that applies the class `Mdict` instead the default Python `dict` as the JSON is decoded.

```
>>> md
{u'a': {u'b': {u'c': {u'd': u'e'}}}}
>>> md['a']
{u'b': {u'c': {u'd': u'e'}}}
>>> md['a']['c']
False
```

The rest of the example here remains the same.

Comment: I like this kind of idea. However, this means I have to convert my JSON output onto my own dictionary right ?

Comment: You can use `object_pairs_hook` with the JSON encoder to apply this as imported.

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was looking for ! Lets me call the dictionary as I am used to, and no other call to a function to check is needed. Perfect :D

Comment: Keep in mind that `False` is also a legit value in a JSON dict. You may want `__missing__` to return a value that is otherwise impossible to decode, such as `object()` to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a recursive function to check:

```
def f(d, keys):
    if not keys:
        return True
    return keys[0] in d and f(d[keys[0]], keys[1:])
```

If the function returns True, the keys exist:

```
In [10]: f(test,"abcd")
Out[10]: True

In [11]: f(test,"abce")
Out[11]: False
```

If you want to test multiple key combinations:

```
for keys in ("abce","abcr","abcd"):
    if f(test,keys):
        print(keys)
        break
abcd
```

To return the value it is pretty simple:

```
def f(d, keys):
    if len(keys) == 1:
         return d[keys[0]] if keys[0] in d else False
    return keys[0] in d and f(d[keys[0]], keys[1:])

print(f(test,"abcd"))
e
```

You can test again for multiple key combinations:

```
def test_keys(keys):
    for keys in keys:
        val = f(test,keys)
        if val:
            return val
    return False


print(test_keys(("abce","abcr","abc")))
```

You can also write the function iteratively:

```
def f(d, keys):
    obj = object
    for k in keys:
        d = d.get(k, obj)
        if d is obj:
            return False
    return d

print(f(test,"abcd"))
e
```

If you want to run a condition based on the return values:

```
def f(d, keys):
    obj = object
    for k in keys:
        d = d.get(k, obj)
        if d is obj:
            return False
    return d

from operator import mul

my_actions = {"c": mul(2, 2), "d": lambda: mul(3, 3), "e": lambda: mul(3, 3)}

for st in ("abce", "abcd", "abcf"):
    val = f(test, st)
    if val:
        print(my_actions[val]())
9
```

Just test the key combo in the same order you would with your if/elif's etc..

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly what you want because it doesn't check existence, but here's a one-liner similar to the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
In [1]: test = {'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':'e'}}}}
In [2]: keys = 'abcd' # or ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [3]: reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k) if d else None, keys, test)
Out[3]: 'e'

In [4]: keys = 'abcf'

In [5]: reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k) if d else None, keys, test)
```

Unfortunately it's not very efficient because it doesn't stop as soon as one of the keys is missing.

Comment: The problem is not to stop if the key is missing - I just don't want to get an exception if the key is missing to be able to evaluate the next possible key.

Comment: @user2497262, as my demo shows, there's no exception raised.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a recursive function.

```
def get_key(d, *args):
    if not args:
        return None
    val = d.get(args[0], None)

    if len(args) == 1:
        return val
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        return get_key(val, *args[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could nest `try` blocks to handle exceptions from both kinds of missing key. Relying on `try` blocks fits the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp) (easier to ask forgiveness than permission) philosophy of Python more than the LBYL (look before you leap) pattern of testing existence before use. In a multithreaded program, it also helps avoid unexpected TOCTTOU (time of check to time of use) behavior caused by another thread modifying the `test` dictionary between the test for existence and the use of the value.

```
try:
    value_abcd = test['a']['b']['c']['d']
except KeyError:
    try:
        value_abf = test['a']['b']['f']
    except KeyError:
        print("do something different")
    else:
        print("value_abf is", value_abf)
else:
    print("value_abcd is", value_abcd)
```

It has since come to my attention that you have far more than two keys. Nesting `try` blocks with this many keys would create an [arrowhead anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804005/how-to-prevent-the-arrowhead-anti-pattern). So instead, you can try the following construction to handle all keys at the same indent level, so long as the access occurs in a function or a `for` loop so that it can `return` or `continue`. If not, [extract a method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

```
try:
    value_abcd = test['a']['b']['c']['d']
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    print("value_abcd is", value_abcd)
    return  # or continue if doing this in a loop

try:
    value_abf = test['a']['b']['f']
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    print("value_abf is", value_abf)
    return

print("do something different")
```

Comment: what happens if the OP has 20 conditions, have 20 nested try/excepts?

Comment: @user2497262 I've edited in an alternate solution that handles multiple keys without making an arrowhead.

Answer (score 0):

Another one for completeness, but checks only for one key recursively:

```py
def hasKey(d, key):
    found = False
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            found = True if k == key else found or hasKey(d[k], key)
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            found = found or hasKey(i, key)
    return found
```

Checks if `key` exists as a key in the nested dict `map`.