# Syntactic sugar for short-circuit-and-assign

Tags: c++, c++14, short-circuiting, syntactic-sugar, bitwise-and

Probably duplicate though I couldn't find a reference.

Similar quotation had been asked: [Short circuit on |= and &= assignment operators in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13046602/1798187) for a different language

## bitwise-and-assign

#### Full syntax

```
bool bRes;
bRes = bRes & SomeFunc()
```

#### Syntactic sugar

```
bool bRes;
bRes &= SomeFunc()
```

## short-circuit-and-assign

#### Full syntax

```
bool bRes;
bRes = bRes && SomeFunc()
```

#### Syntactic sugar

```
bool bRes;
???
```

## Question

Is there a syntactic sugar for short-circuit-and-assign?

Comment: I'm almost certain I remember seeing this before. It had a lengthy discussion  about the topic too.

Comment: Yes. It is very likely. Couldn't find it though.

Comment: wouldnt a `bool bool::operator &&= ( bool)` need to evaluate its parameter, making the shortcircuiting impossible?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Did you mean this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488406/why-doesnt-c-have-or-for-booleans

Comment: Found it, but it's a discussion of why such syntax doesn't exist (in Java): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-co

Comment: OK great. so closing this one I guess..